# Const Static Function Pointer in Class ~ How to initialize it?

Tags: c++

I have this small piece of code:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

class A
{
public:
    const static int (*FP)(int, int) = &add;
};

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 2;
    int z = A::FP(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Under VS2012 this generates the following error:
error C2864: 'A::FP' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class.

Is there something I am not seeing? Or is it plainly not possible for some reason?

Christian

Comment: Can you set it in the class constructor initialisation list?

Comment: There is no hidden meaning in the error message. "Only static const integral data members" means exactly what it says. As function pointers are not integral, you cannot do that. Initialize them outside of the class in a .cpp file.

Comment: @n.m Thanks for explaning what integral data members are. I am not native English so sometimes it's an adventure finding out those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize outside of the class definition, using a `typedef` to make the `const`ness possible:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(int, int);

class A
{
public:
    const static func_t FP;
};

const func_t A::FP = &add;
```

Without the `typedef` the declaration:

```
const static int (*FP)(int, int) = &add;
```

is a `static` function pointer named `FP` with a return type of `const int`, not a `const` function pointer. When compiled with warnling level `/W4` the following diagnostic is emitted:

> warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored

this was not immediately apparent due to the ordering of the declaration, `const static int` instead of `static const int`.

Comment: Is it even correct without a typedef? The `const` belongs to the return type without it, doesn't it?

Comment: @jrok, yes. I couldn't determine a way to create it with a `const` without the `typedef` as the `const int ...` was being treated as the `return` type.

Comment: Well, the same thing should happen in the declaration in the class, too. So I wonder why gcc complains about invalid conversion from `const int (*)(int, int)` to `int (*)(int, int)`.

Comment: @jrok, VC compiler warns about meaningless qualifier at both declartaion and definition.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03. In class initialization of `non-intgeral` or `enum` `data-types` is not allowed.

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef int (*FP_ptr)(int, int);
    const static FP_ptr FP;
};

const A::FP_ptr 
A::FP = &add;
```

---

C++11

```
class A
{
public:
    constexpr static int (*FP)(int, int) = &add;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the C++11 version too! Just a shame Visual Studio doesn't support this C++11 feature yet...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, guys. I had pretty much the same problem recently. Just want to add the answer with "const" in the right place without declaring a new type:

```
class A
{
public:
    static int (* const FP)(int, int);
};

int (* const A::FP)(int, int) = &add;
```

It is okay, to change the last line to(I am not sure if it is exactly the same thing, but it works):

```
int (* const A::FP)(int, int) = add;
```

The other way (how other people solve similar issue) would be something like:

```
class A
{
public:
    static int FP(int, int);
};

int A::FP(int x, int y)
{
    return add( &x, &y );
}
```